# add two times when the format is hours minutes using moment.js

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to add two dates which are in the format of `hours & minutes` using `moment.js`. But the result is giving `invalid`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table-class").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find(".timeClass").each(function() {

      var value = $(this).val();

      var start = moment(value, 'h:mma');
      console.log(start);
      total += start;

    });
    $(".total").text(moment(total, 'h:mma'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-class">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1 hour 30 mins" class="timeClass">
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="3 hours 02 mins" class="timeClass">
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<p class="total">

</p>
```

Any suggestions please, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to parse your input (e.g. 1 hour 30 mins) the right way, so you can use `'h [hour] mm [mins]'` instead of `'h:mma'`. See [Escaping charaters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters) section of the docs. Anyway this is a workaround because "1 hour 30 mins" and "3 hours 02 mins" are likely durations, they do not represent a given moment in time.

As [Default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section states, momentjs:

> Defaulting to today, when only hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds are passed

So using `moment(value, 'h [hour] mm [mins]');` you are creating a moment for the current day. You can get the number of milliseconds since the start of the day using [`diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

Finally, you can create a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object from your `total` variable using [`moment.duration(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/). You can show the value of moment duration using [`hours()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/) and [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) or using [`format()`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) method of [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in.

Here a live sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table-class").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find(".timeClass").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();

      var start = moment(value, 'h [hour] mm [mins]');
      var diff = start.diff(start.clone().startOf('d'));
      total += diff;

    });
    var dur = moment.duration(total);
    $(".total").text(dur.hours() + ':' + dur.minutes());
    // Using moment-duration-format:
    //$(".total").text(dur.format('h:mm'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-class">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="1 hour 30 mins" class="timeClass">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="3 hours 02 mins" class="timeClass">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p class="total"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)